# Is there a simple way to add a sparse matrix to an LU decomposition of a dense matrix?

Tags: lapack, matrix-factorization, parabolic-pde

I am solving a parabolic equation in the form:

$$
\left( {M \over\tau_j} + A \right) u^{j+1} = M f^j + {u^j \over \tau_j},
$$

where $A$ and $f$ are a dense stiffness matrix and the right hand side of the fractional diffusion problem from this paper:

[Acosta, Gabriel & Bersetche, Francisco & Borthagaray, Juan. (2017). A short FE implementation for a 2d homogeneous Dirichlet problem of a Fractional Laplacian. Computers & Mathematics with Applications. 784-816. 10.1016/j.camwa.2017.05.026. ]

$M$ is the matrix of mass, $u^j$ is the solution at a previous time step and $u^{j+1}$ is the vector of unknowns. $\tau_j$ is a number.

I have previously solved the non-parabolic problem $Au = B$ with LU decomposition through lapack's `dgesv` function.

$M$ is a sparse matrix with around 5 elements per row. It could also be reduced to a diagonal matrix (lumping of mass) by summing all coefficients to the diagonal element.

So my question is: is it possible to calculate $A = LU$ once and then only update the $LU$ factorization with the $M \over \sigma_j$ for each step?

I have a vague memory that I found a lecture notes or a textbook online about it a few months ago. Alas my google-fu is failing me right now. I tried googling for "parabolic equations solution with LU" and a few other variants about parabolic equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another factorization you could consider: the Hessenberg upper-triangular reduction. It's usually used as a preprocessing step in the QZ algorithm, but it has other uses as well.

Consider the reduction $(A,M) = Q^T(H,T)Z$. Then $\frac{M}{\mu_j} + A = Q^T(\frac{T}{\mu_j} + H)Z$, which is relatively cheap to solve as it only involves orthogonal matrices and a Hessenberg matrix. This is valid for any value of $\mu_j$, so long as the matrices $A$ and $M$ don't change.

However, the Hessenberg upper-triangular reduction is pretty expensive. This is only going to be worth it if you have a whole lot of systems to solve.

Comment: That is an interesting idea. Are there effective parallel implementations of it?
The part of the problem that I didn't mention is that I am using LU from LAPACK (MKL and PLASMA, etc). And it has very good parallel speed-up.

Comment: Quick experiment on my laptop, a single LU of matrices of size 4000 takes about 0.39s. A HT reduction takes about 29s. That's almost 100 times slower. This is likely to get worse for larger matrices as the LU scales a bit better.

Comment: If you end up trying this idea, i have a pretty fast implementation of the HT reduction on GPU. The paper is not ready for publication, but i can provide you a copy via email if you want.

Comment: I have a model problem, so I can make it as big as I want. The sky is the limit. My work mail is dimitargslavchev@parallel.bas.bg. I will not use it for my current work due to time constrains, but will discuss it with my advisor for a later work.

Comment: Also thanks for your time and answer.

Answer (score 4):

And just a few minutes after asking I found an answer. The procedure above is called "updating LU". This question has a nice generic answer with links to other more specific questions.

[full rank update to cholesky decomposition](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10630/full-rank-update-to-cholesky-decomposition)

So the short answer is no, in my case. You cannot update LU decomposition with a full rank matrix in less than $O(n^3)$, which is the same as performing the decomposition again if the update is full rank. And the matrix of mass is full rank, I believe.

EDIT: Another option is going around the problem by replacing the LU decomposition with something else. For example:

1. One can use Hessenberg upper-triangular reduction as advised by Thijs Steel in another answer
2. With Hierarchical methods to compress the matrix $A$ and then do updates on the compressed matrix before factorization. Provided that $A$ is suitable for compression. I do use Hierarchical Semo-separable compression from STRUMPACK for that, but this question was to see if there is a way to "optimize" the direct gaussian solver.
3. Or other options that I am not aware of.

Comment: You might be able to use the LU decomposition as a preconditioner in an iterative solution of the full system, allowing you to solve with just a few iterations. It might work for a few time steps and then you may need to recompute the LU factorization.

Comment: I agree with your assessment that the general full update of the LU decomposition is not worth the effort. However, if $M$ is diagonal, then it might be worth investigating a series of rank-1 updates to your decomposition. I suspect even that is not worth the headache involved, and may introduce undesirable numerical side effects since you intend to update your factorization many times.

Comment: Yes, this might be the most asked question here. There is no known way to make full-rank updates of LU decomposition, not even if you just want to add a multiple of the identity.

Comment: I am making a comparison between using Gaussian solver and HSS compression (from STRUMPACK).
And with HSS compression, I can just use the compressed matrix $H$ over and over again. Well for the lumped matrix of mass at least, since the compression doesn't touch the diagonal.